# How to inhibit keyboard backlight timeout?

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, 19.10, backlight

Ubuntu 19.10 - On my HP 14-dq1044cl (the recent Costco $279 special) the keyboard backlight automatically turns off after ~20 seconds. Pressing any key turns the backlight on again but this is problematic in a dark room for several reasons. This timeout is not reset or inhibited by touchpad use. When I run Windows 10 on the same machine, at least touchpad use will reset the timer and the backlight will stay on (for significantly longer than 20 seconds). 
There is no BIOS option to configure the keyboard backlight.
Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can change keyboard backlight settings in `kbd_backlight/stop_timeout` file (on a Dell machine the folder [may instead be named](https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-us/sln308123/how-to-configure-the-keyboard-backlight-time-out-interval-in-ubuntu-linux?lang=en) `dell::kbd_backlight`).
To find location of keyboard backlight configuration file according to your keyboard, you can execute following command in terminal.

```
sudo find /sys/devices/ -name "*kbd_backlight"
```

You can configure timeout in seconds.

```
sudo nano <full path of kbd_backlight dir>/stop_timeout
```

Enter value in seconds, save file and exit.

Comment: Thank you but I found no such file(s) under the /sys/devices tree. The only files which name contains the word "backlight" pertain to the display backlight.

Comment: does "xled on" work? you might need to install xled. if that works make a loop script to set it on periodically. add that script to the startup

Comment: "xled" package does not seem to be installed in or available to the standard Ubuntu 19.10 installation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however it works fine but when I restart the laptop the stop_timeout interval value changes to default i.e. "10s". Can you please address this

Comment: if you have a Dell Laptop, new BIOS have a keyboard backlight timeout setting which overrides anything i put on that file setting, so just change the BIOS setting